# vb.net datagridview and bindingsource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

Im in the process over converting some legacy VB6 code over, in particular a TDBGrid linked to an ADODC data control.

Everything is going ok, ive got my columns and bindignsource reading sweet as a nut and performing what its supposed to do, correctly - but im having a problem converting this type of method over.

In the vb6 app, while a user scrolls through the grid, the grid fetchstyle (similar to cellformatting) go looking at the equivalent row of data in the adodc.

In .net, I cant seem to get that functionality to be the same, unless I add that field from the database, into a column in the grid and make it invisible (which I dont really want to be doing if i can help it) then read the cell via cellformatting and then perform some action, such as changing the cellstyle backcolor to something.

Is it possible to refer to a row in the bindingsource that would be the same row in the grid that a user is at, without having that field from the bindingsource - in a DGV column?

or do i just have to put up with placing more columns in the DGV than I want and just live with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [BindingSource.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.current(v=vs.110).aspx)
 object.

Comment: I've used the BindingSource.Current object but it only works when you're clicking through the datagridview, not during the record-processing in the cellformatting. i.e. if you refresh a bindingsource that has been linked to the datagridview, the bindingsource.current remains at the top while the datagridview goes fetching data from the bindingsource. Maybe I've done something wrong - I'll go have a play today - thanks for replying though GMan